# Excel macro is not working

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, macros

I had successfully created a macro, but had to keep recreating it for every Excel doc I wanted to use it in. Now it won't work for any of the workbooks.

```
Function GetURL(rng As Range) As String
  On Error Resume Next
  GetURL = rng.Hyperlinks(1).Address
End Function
```

What I would like to do is activate this macro across ALL workbooks, anytime I open Excel and use `=GetURL(A1)` I want it to get the HTTP link.

Comment: Tip: avoid using `On Error Resume Next` because it doesn't let you gracefully handle errors on a granular basis.

Comment: What do you mean by "won't work"?  What happens?

Comment: Also, how do you want your macro to work if a workbook doesn't have any hyperlinks? You write "I want it to get the HTTP link" without being clear about what the link is - or how it's created, or what happens if there isn't one - or if there are multiple links.

Comment: To use it in any workbook on your computer.  Create a personal.xlsb workbook for the vba.  Put this in one of those modules.  Then you would call it `=Personal.xlsb!GetURL(A1)`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches that I can think about to perform this:

1. Make an Add In that would contain your UDF and install properly 

[Official Documentantion](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/151490)
I think this is the best approach due to your statement

> *Quote: anytime I open Excel and use =GetURL(A1) I want it to get the HTTP link.*>

2. You may use the UDF from the original workbook like so:

```
=Book1.xlsm!GetURL(A1)
```

As long as the workbook is opened